# Vue JS widgets in hybrid application

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a hybrid Django/VueJS application. I combine Django templating pages with VueJS widgets because that allows to take best of the 2 different worlds. However, I face an issue when I need to place multiple VueJS widgets. When I need to embed only 1 widget, I just use  to embed it. But when I have multiple widgets, I don't know what to do.

Do I need to mount multiple widget separately? Is this a good practice?

Here's how my main.js looks like:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import router from "./router";
import AccountApp from "./AccountApp.vue";
import store from "./store/index.js";
import i18n from "./i18n";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const accountApp = new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(AccountApp),
});

accountApp.$mount("#app");
```

Could this be a possible solution?

```
import Vue from "vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import router from "./router";
import AccountApp from "./AccountApp.vue";
import UserApp from "./UserApp.vue";
import store from "./store/index.js";
import i18n from "./i18n";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const accountApp = new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(AccountApp),
});

accountApp.$mount("#account");


const userApp = new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  i18n,
  render: (h) => h(UserApp),
});

userApp.$mount("#user");
```

Comment: *Do I need to mount multiple widget separately? Is this a good practice?* - yes, that's it, unless they need to communicate on client side.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: There's no best way. A preferable way depends on a specific case. The question doesn't contain enough information. Why do you have `router` in widgets? You can use it for app state but it needs to be in-memory because browser url is shared between them.